# Solving ordinary differential equations of order 2

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm struggling solving this linear ODE:

> $$y''(x) + 2y'(x) = -4$$

I solved the homogeneous solution for this equation: $c_1 + c_2 e^{-2x}$ for some constants $c_1$, $c_2$;

But I'm struggling with the non-homogeneous part:
If I choose $y_p(x) = C$ for some constant $C$, then $y_p' = 0$, $y_p'' = 0$. Plugging this equations into the original one, this would yield: $0 = -4$.

What am I doing wrong! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can follow the hint of Robert Z. For this particular second-order ODE it might be easier to reduce it to first order, as $y$ does not appear: define $z := y'$ to obtain a first-order linear ODE for $z$. Solve for $z$, then integrate once to obtain $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Since $0$ is a solution of multiplicity $1$ of the characteristic equation $z^2+2z=0$ and $-4$ is a polynomial of zero degree then, by the [Method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients#Typical_forms_of_the_particular_integral), you should try as a particular solution the following form
$$y_p(x)=x\cdot C$$
where $C$ is a constant to be determined.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totolly forgot that I have to multiply C with x . Now it makes sense! :)